# Kicking member using commando

Tags: discord.js, commando

So I am trying to write code to kick a member of the server.

```
async run (commandoMsg, userId) {
        let guild = commandoMsg.guild;
        //console.log(guild.members.fetch(userId));
        let member = guild.members.fetch(userId);
        member.kick('Kicking...')
        .then(m => console.log('kicked'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I get an error saying
`TypeError: member.kick is not a function`
How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

`let member = guild.members.fetch(userId);`, so `member` returns undefined which means the member's ID is not found.
You mean using like this `guild.members.cache.get(userId)`?
Here's your fixed code:

```js
async run (commandoMsg, userId) {
   let guild = commandoMsg.guild;
   let member = guild.members.cache.get(userId);
   member.kick('Kicking...')
         .then(m => console.log('kicked'))
         .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

*btw, if you're not using discord.js v12, then use `guild.members.get(userId)` instead of `guild.members.cache.get(userId)`*